# Post composition of integral

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, integration, integral-operators

**Setup:**

If $\langle \Omega, \mathfrak{F},\mu \rangle$ is a measure space, $f:\Omega \rightarrow E$ is a weakly-measurable function to a Banach space $E$, $g: E \rightarrow E'$ is a diffeomorphism and for simplicity say $E$ is reflexive.

Recall that the $E$-valued Dunford-Pettis integral of $f$ over $\Omega$ is defined as the (unique) solution $e$ to:
\begin{equation}
(\forall x^* \in E^*)\, x^*(e) = \int_{\Omega} x^*(f(\omega)) d\mu(\omega)
\end{equation}
and we *denote it* by $\int_\Omega f d\mu$.

---

**Question 1**

My question is: is it true that:
$g(\int_{\Omega} f d\mu) = \int_{\Omega} g \circ f d\mu  $,
where the integral here are the Pettis integrals?

---

**Question 2**
Since question $1$ was shown to be false, for what $g$ if is does the above equation hold true in general (if any)?

Comment: Can you define $\int_E f$ where  $f:\Omega\to E$?

Comment: Its the unique $e\in E$ solving: 
$(x^* \in E^*)\, x^*(e) = \int x^*(f) $ (where the right is the Lebesgue integral).

Comment: I meant, what do you mean by the integral of $f$ over $E$ when $f$ is defined on $\Omega$?

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my notation.

Comment: Do you mean $x^*(f)$ instead of $x^*(e)$? And I still don't get what is denoted by $\int_E f d \mu$, because the expression above seems to be dependent on the choice of $x^* \in E$. Moreover, $x$ is an element of $\Omega$ and $x^*$ of $E$? I apologize for the annoying intrusion...

Comment: It's okay, I clarified the notation further.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. But I still think that your defining formula should read
$$(\forall x^* \in E^*)\quad x^*(f) = \int_\Omega x^*(f(\omega)) d\mu(\omega).$$
Then $\int_E f d \mu \in E^{**} \simeq E$ is the mapping $(\int_E f d \mu)(x^*) = x^*(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any linear map $g: E \rightarrow E'$.

The proof of this can be found in [these notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/07e_vv_integrals.pdf).

Comment: Did you expect some _nonlinear_ diffeomorphisms would qualify ??

Comment: Only linear diffeos qualify

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought only linear involutions work..